# Is there a way to maintain the scrollbar position On a page refresh (Without Javascript)?

Tags: php, css, html

I am building a system where users can edit content inline, however a requirement of the project is:

**`No Javascript!`**

Is there a way using just php, html and css to maintain the scrollbar position on a page refresh so when an edit button is clicked the page doesn't jump up to the top?

any suggestions?

Comment: That's very generic. If you are using hash urls it is very easy though. If you need the exact and random position of the scrollbar, that is probably impossible without JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect place for progressive enhancement.  If there is no javascript, then use the named anchor tag (as Olli mentions) and a hash on the URL to get it close (but it won't be exact).

If there is javascript, then save the scroll position to a cookie or URL parameter and restore the scroll position exactly when the page reloads.

There should be no harm in offering the best experience you can without javascript, but offering a better one when javascript is available (progressive enhancement).

Another possibility is to use a paged or tabbed interface (to position the edit field near the top of the window) so it's a lot less likely that there is any scrolling when the field is edited.

Comment: i'll leave it for a bit just to see if anyone else has anything to say, but i have a feeling your right.

Comment: Or you could do both javascript and plain HTML. This would be 100% sure option

Answer (score 3):

Do it so:

```
<a name="jumphere"></a>
```

and when you have edited

```
http://yourUrlHere.com/somepage.php#jumphere
```